# URLs are not working in Deployed website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis, redirect

I am deploying a website on IIS and have an issue with URLs. The URL works correctly in visual studio but when I publish it on IIS, it doesn't work.

For example:

In visual studio following URL works correctly:

```
<img src="/Content/images/nopic.jpg" style="width: 105%;" >
```

For deployed version URL needs a change:

```
<img src="/tlsv2/Content/images/nopic.jpg" style="width: 105%;" >
```

Comment: Use `<img src="~/Content/images/nopic.jpg" ..>` (leading tilde character)

Comment: i have tried this but it not works in Visual Studio :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **Url.Content** like this,

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/nopic.jpg")" style="width: 105%;" >
```

The '`~`' helps to translates the correct url. For example if '`tlsv2`' is your virtual directory then, it will translate above url to:

```
/tlsv2/Content/images/nopic.jpg
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "~" symbol as follow, it will reflect the deployed URL

For example:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/nopic.jpg" style="width: 105%;" >
```